# "Unable to move file" error during manual publish to Zip od Azure function App in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-publish

I have set up deployment of my VS project, so that I have to manually publish to Azure function App.

Unfortunately, I recently got an error:

```
> Unable to move file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ssdk01mh.2d4\publishout\bin\some.dll to  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ssdk01mh.2d4\publishout\some.dll Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

It occurs the same for Azure function deployment and to Folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run repair Visual Studio installation, it helped in my case
[image]